# Applying font scale to LableStyle in Scene2D with Skins

Tags: java, libgdx, skin, scene2d

I'm trying to apply a font scale to an individual font style within the skin.json file for Scene2D.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: 
    {  
        default: { font: gameFont, fontColor: white, fontScaleX:0.5, fontScaleY:0.5}
    }
```

I was under the impression that Scene2D was simply using refection to override values. I get the following error now:

```
Field not found: fontScaleX (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle)
```

BUT

The field clearly exists:

```
private float fontScaleX = 1, fontScaleY = 1;
```

Example of how I'm currently doing it:

```
Label one = new Label("One", AssetController.getInstance().getDefaultSkin(), "defaultLabel");
one.setFontScale(Values.FONT_SCALE_SMALL);
```

Example of what would be nice.

```
Label one = new Label("One", AssetController.getInstance().getDefaultSkin(), "defaultLabelBig");
```

I've looked around and people have said use different bitmap fonts. I don't think this is an option as we'd have to load each one vs. memory.

Comment: `fontScaleX` and `fontScaleY` are not part of the `LabelStyle` class, they are part of the encapsulating `Label` class.  This is why it's not being found.  So either you have to set it with the `Label` itself, or with the `BitmapFont` that is being assigned to it.

Comment: That being said, to address your other complaint, forget what people say about multiple `BitmapFonts`.  For someone like me, that was unfeasible because I needed about 15 different sizes.  `DistanceFieldFont` is what you want to look into for that.  Only issue is that you can't instantiate `DistanceFieldFonts` in skin.json files because it doesn't have a no-argument constructor.